# How to explore audit workbench through fortify software security center?

Tags: fortify

How do I explore fortify audit workbench from Software security centre? Can I get auditing capabilities in SSC like in audit workbench?

Answer (score 4):

Static code analyzer (SCA) is a command line program run on a developer workstation or run on a development or test build server. You typically use SCA to scan the code (via sourceanalyzer or the sourceanalyzer.jar) and generate an Fortify Project Reports (FPR) file. Then you can open that FPR file with Audit Workbench or upload it to SSC, where you can track trends, risk posture, etc.

Audit Workbench (AWB) is installed on your desktop with the SCA; it is a graphical application that allows you to review the scan results, add audit data, apply filters, and run simple reports. The AWB only gives you the results of that particular scan. In contrast, the SSC provides the history of your applications and the other applications using the SSC (given the appropriate access permissions).

The SSC is a web-based repository of your FPR files and tool for managing our portfolio's application security. It is a java war installed into tomcat or your favorite application server. The reports on SSC are better suited to running centralized metrics. You can report on the results of a particular scan, or the history (what changed between the current scan and any earlier ones). If you want diff's, trends, history etc of SCA scans, use SSC to report Fortify issues and remediation over time. Trend reports and portfolio reports are available only on the SSC.

The same sourceanalyzer.exe (the SCA executable) is invoked by the Audit Workbench and by the various SCA plug-ins (maven, Jenkins, eclipse, Visual Studio, IntelliJ, XCode, etc). The SSC does not run the SCA. The SSC manages the FPR files that are output from the SCA and manage your audits of the issues that SCA finds. The SSC does not run the SCA. The SSC manages the FPR files that are output from the SCA.